# High ping to server, traceroute issue?

Tags: ping, traceroute, packet-loss

My friend and I have the same type of internet connection (ADSL 2+) and we get similar speeds (10 down 1 up) and ping, but when we both try to connect to the same IP we get different pings. We are trying to connect to a server in canada (158.69.135.112) from australia and I get a much higher ping, though if we both ping an IP in the US or UK we get a very similar ping. Here are our traceroute results.

***My Traceroute***

```
C:\Users\Baiden>tracert 158.69.135.112

Tracing route to 158.69.135.112 over a maximum of 30 hops

1     3 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  dsldevice.gateway [10.0.0.138]
2    22 ms    22 ms    26 ms  172.18.208.11
3    21 ms    23 ms    22 ms  172.18.92.1
4    23 ms    22 ms    23 ms  bundle-ether4.ken-edge902.sydney.telstra.net [203.50.12.106]
5    24 ms    23 ms    23 ms  bundle-ether14.ken-core10.sydney.telstra.net [203.50.11.96]
6    28 ms    58 ms    30 ms  bundle-ether1.pad-gw11.sydney.telstra.net [203.50.6.61]
7    24 ms    27 ms    26 ms  bundle-ether1.sydp-core04.sydney.reach.com [203.50.13.90]
8   166 ms   166 ms   166 ms  i-0-1-0-5.paix-core01.bx.telstraglobal.net [202.84.140.58]
9   166 ms   165 ms   164 ms  i-0-5-0-1.paix02.bi.telstraglobal.net [202.40.149.110]
10   168 ms   158 ms   179 ms  xe-5-3-0.paloalto2.pao.seabone.net [195.22.206.129]
11   262 ms   252 ms   254 ms  et-4-3-0.miami15.mia.seabone.net [195.22.199.177]
12   333 ms   254 ms   245 ms  et-10-1-0.miami15.mia.seabone.net [89.221.41.175]
13     *      430 ms     *     po99-155.mia-5-6k.fl.us [178.32.135.208]
14   476 ms   457 ms     *     be100-1035.nwk-1-a9.nj.us [198.27.73.197]
15   430 ms   429 ms   434 ms  be10-1037.bhs-g1-a9.qc.ca [192.99.146.99]
16   437 ms   439 ms   441 ms  bhs-3a-a9.qc.ca [198.27.73.92]
17   441 ms   428 ms   427 ms  158.69.135.112

Trace complete.
```

***Friend's Traceroute***

```
Tracing route to 158.69.135.112 over a maximum of 30 hops

1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  m.home [10.0.0.138]
2    89 ms    39 ms    40 ms  172.18.210.19
3    64 ms    69 ms    66 ms  172.18.68.157
4    45 ms    45 ms    39 ms  bundle-ether4.lon-edge902.melbourne.telstra.net [203.50.76.12]
5    64 ms    47 ms    39 ms  bundle-ether11.exi-core10.melbourne.telstra.net [203.50.11.113]
6    57 ms    59 ms    60 ms  bundle-ether12.chw-core10.sydney.telstra.net [203.50.11.124]
7    66 ms    66 ms    68 ms  bundle-ether1.oxf-gw11.sydney.telstra.net [203.50.6.93]
8    62 ms   181 ms    57 ms  bundle-ether1.sydo-core03.sydney.reach.com [203.50.13.98]
9    61 ms    65 ms    62 ms  i-0-1-0-16.sydo-core04.bi.telstraglobal.net [202.84.222.58]
10   195 ms   210 ms   239 ms  i-0-2-0-0.1wlt-core01.bx.telstraglobal.net [202.84.141.146]
11   355 ms   228 ms   231 ms  i-0-5-0-5.eqla01.bi.telstraglobal.net [202.84.253.30]
12   233 ms   218 ms   208 ms  unknown.telstraglobal.net [134.159.63.171]
13     *      274 ms   257 ms  if-6-20.tcore2.LVW-Los-Angeles.as6453.net [64.86.252.65]
14   301 ms   272 ms   288 ms  if-2-2.tcore1.LVW-Los-Angeles.as6453.net [66.110.59.1]
15   280 ms   278 ms   305 ms  if-8-2.tcore2.DT8-Dallas.as6453.net [66.110.57.81]
16   266 ms   260 ms   263 ms  if-2-2.tcore1.DT8-Dallas.as6453.net [66.110.56.5]
17   295 ms   335 ms   261 ms  if-23-2.tcore2.CT8-Chicago.as6453.net [64.86.79.120]
18   268 ms   269 ms   279 ms  if-22-2.tcore1.CT8-Chicago.as6453.net [64.86.79.2]
19   295 ms   299 ms   290 ms  be100-152.chi-5-a9.il.us [198.27.73.69]
20   338 ms   349 ms   317 ms  be10-1218.bhs-g2-a9.qc.ca [198.27.73.89]
21   327 ms   315 ms   331 ms  bhs-3a-a9.qc.ca [198.27.73.94]
22   301 ms   313 ms   315 ms  158.69.135.112

Trace complete.
```

My friend ends up with over 100ms ping less than me, is there a problem with the traceroute? I notice between hops 12 and 13 on the first traceroute there is a big jump, could this be an issue? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your friend has a better route than yours. He pass through Chigago and you by Miami. Maybe Miami is experiencing some link saturation or even a route flapping. I'm OVH customer too and I have no problem in the routes through Miami (maybe cause I'm reaching by another OVH router port). As you live in Australia, I recommend you to host in OVH UK or FR.

```
C:\Users\Victor>tracert 158.69.135.112

Rastreando a rota para 158.69.135.112 com no máximo 30 saltos

  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.168.1
  3     4 ms     2 ms     2 ms  186-225-128-155.oquei.com.br [186.225.128.155]
  4     5 ms     3 ms    24 ms  186-225-128-1.oquei.com.br [186.225.128.1]
  5     3 ms     3 ms     2 ms  186-225-147-89.customer.sinalbr.com.br [186.225.147.89]
  6     4 ms     3 ms     3 ms  xe-0-0-1-411.edge-a.srr001.algartelecom.com.br [187.72.97.206]
  7    14 ms    13 ms    14 ms  et-8-0-3-0.ptx-a.rpo008.algartelecom.com.br [201.48.48.157]
  8    16 ms    16 ms    16 ms  et-14-0-0-0.ptx-a.cas512.algartelecom.com.br [201.48.45.90]
  9    19 ms    16 ms    18 ms  et-8-0-1-0.ptx-a.spo-piaf.algartelecom.com.br [201.48.48.254]
 10   118 ms   133 ms   119 ms  ae0-0.border-b.mia.algartelecom.com.br [201.48.45.166]
 11   143 ms     *      118 ms  198.32.125.64
 12   151 ms   148 ms   151 ms  be100-1036.nwk-1-a9.nj.us [198.27.73.199]
 13   156 ms   160 ms   160 ms  be10-1037.bhs-g1-a9.qc.ca [192.99.146.99]
 14   160 ms   158 ms   158 ms  bhs-3a-a9.qc.ca [198.27.73.92]
 15   156 ms   157 ms   155 ms  158.69.135.112

Rastreamento concluído.
```